# Search Repeating element in array and compare it's index to anther array for Summation

Tags: java, arrays, string, sum

I have two `int arr1[] = {1 2 1 1 2 1 }`  and `string arr2[] = {a b c b b a}` Arrays. I want to find repeating element in **arr2**. Suppose **a** is reapting in index **0** and **5**. So I want to sum of index **0** and **5** in **arr1** and print the repeating value with its summation.

Comment: What did you try so far ? What isn't behaving as you expect ? Show us some code first.

Comment: actually this is part of a another problem, so i did not post whole question for neatness.

Comment: Are you doing this in java or javascript?

Comment: in java @azurefrog

Comment: You might want to remove the javascript tag, then, since that's a completely different language.

Comment: @bignums Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, we won't help you without seeing a minimal effort from your side. Show us some code, and we'll help you getting it to work !

Answer (score 0):

Here's are quick functions to answer your question regarding the integer array.

```
int count_occur(string arr2[], int arr1[], string repeated) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr2[i] == repeated) sum += arr1[i];
    }

    return count;
}

void repeated_sum() {
     int[] arr1 = new int[]{1,2,1,1,2,1};    //given array
     string arr2[] = {"a","b","c","b","b","a"}
     string repeat = "a";                          //number to count repeats    

     int result = count_occur(arr2, arr1, repeat); //count repeats and multiply to get the summation
     System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TNTFreaks  but that's not what a want. You did the sum of an Int Array. What i want is in String Array not in Array of Int. If there is a same element in array of string for example, ( in my array [a, b, c, b, b, a]  **a** is in index in index **0** and **5**, so now i want to sum of index **0** and **5** in my **IntArray** ), do the sum of the same index number's element in Integer Array.

Comment: Ah @bignums, I apologize. I can come up with a solution for you in a bit

Comment: @bignums check it out now

Comment: @ TNTFreaks Okay it's working, but  it's also not what i want. Because the code is for only one element. We have to change every element in the `repeat` string. I want a loop that accept all the element one by one and check for all the element in the array. I hope this time you understand well. Suppose we have to check for element `b` then we have a loop that check for `b` in the array and print the sum. but the main thing is when loop comes at another `b` after check `index[1]` `b`, this time `b` must be skip because we already printed its summation value before. Need to make it dynamic.